# General syntax for plotting graphs in SAS

Tags: sas

I am looking for syntax of most commonly used Procs for plotting Grpahs in SAS. Specifically syntax for line chart, overlay plots, bar charts, scatter plots, Tree Maps etc

Comment: Don't use SAS/GRAPH, you're looking for SGPLOT and you can find all your base examples here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=n19gxtzyuf79t3n16g5v26b73ckv.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n0z1ipl5ivwi4yn1vaeq2al0rv8u

Answer (score 1):

```
ods escapechar='^';   
options orientation=LANDSCAPE nodate nonumber;
ods listing close;
ods pdf file="abcd.pdf"
nogfootnote nogtitle pdftoc=0;
ods noproctitle;

title;
title2;
ods pdf startpage=now;
ods proclabel = "name insights";
title h=16pt bold font='times roman' "Y1 Vs Y2";
title5 h=15pt bold font='times roman' "Name in name1";
footnote1 h=7pt font='times roman' j=r "Prepared by ABCD on date for name";
footnote2 h=7pt j=r font='times roman' 'Proprietary' font='times roman' h=8pt j=l 'Page ^{thispage}';

proc sgplot data=inputdataset(where=(var1=999));
    series x = days y = yvalue1 / 
                    legendlabel = "Y Value 1" name='y1'
                    lineattrs = (thickness = 3 color =cx0083be  pattern = 4);
    series x = days y = yvalue2 / 
                    legendlabel = "Y Value 2"
                    name='y2'
                    lineattrs = (thickness = 2 color = brown pattern = 1);
    scatter x= &x_point y=&y_point1./
                    legendlabel='Y Point 1' name='ypoint1'
                    MARKERATTRS=(symbol=diamond color=orange);
    scatter x= &x_point y=&y_point2./
                    legendlabel='Y Point 2' name='ypoint2'
                    MARKERATTRS=(symbol=circle color=red);
    xaxis  label = "Days";
    yaxis  label = "Response" min=0 max=1;
    keylegend 'y1' 'y2' 'ypoint1' 'ypoint2'/position=bottom across=2 down=2;
quit;

proc sgplot data=input2;
    label XGroup="X Group";
    histogram Response/nbins=10 group=groupvar showbins scale=COUNT;
    refline &ref1/axis=x lineattrs=(color=blue) legendlabel='Ref 1' name='s_r';
    refline &ref2/axis=x lineattrs=(color=red) legendlabel='Ref 2' name='r2';;
    yaxis label="Count";
    xaxis label="Response" max=&max.;
    keylegend 'r1' 'r2'/position=bottom down=3;
quit;

proc sgpanel data=input3;
    panelby panelvar;
    vbar on_xaxis_var/response=y_axis_var;
run;

proc sgpanel data=input4;
    panelby panelvar/onepanel skipemptycells columns=4 COLHEADERPOS=bottom NOVARNAME;
    vbar on_xaxis_var/response=yvar stat=mean barwidth=0.2 fillattrs=(color=brown);
    rowaxis label='Average';
    colaxis label='on_xaxis_var';
run;

%let e1 = The above graph compares Y1 to ;
%let e2 = Y2 for name in name1;
title;
footnote;
ods pdf text= "^S={font_size=10pt}";
ods pdf text ="^S={just=left font=('times roman',
11pt)}&e1 &e2";
ods pdf text= "^S={font_size=10pt}";
ods pdf text ="^S={just=left font=('times roman',
11pt)}&e3 &e4 &e5 &e6 &e7";

ods pdf close;
```

Comment: You can also add a brief comment on what this snippet of code does to help the readers

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is easier to use a UI to make a graph and then look at what the UI code generator created.

What SAS client are you using ?

Display Manager? Try Graph'n Go `dm "gng" gng;`
  - Create a graph and export as SAS code

Enterprise Guide? Try Tasks/Graph
  - Create a graph and examine the code